# Magento2: Varnish Test result fail

Tags: magento2, cache, varnish, cookie

I'm trying to submit an extension for Magento 2.4 but can't pass the "Varnish Test" stage because of the cache that can't be set up on some pages (simple-product and category):

> "Expected HIT on the second page load.": ... 
> "Expected HIT on the second page load after product price update.": ...

I suppose in my case this error is due to the fact that I create cookies from my module code which could prevent the activation of the Varnish cache.

I have created two Observers on "controller_front_send_response_before" and "controller_action_postdispatch" events in which I create cookies with product information. I then retrieve and process this data from the front in JavaScript.

For my local tests, I have activated the varnish cache. When I request a product page or a category I can see the header "X-Magento-Cache-Debug: HIT".

Do you know if there are any special recommendations to follow regarding the creation of cookies in Magento 2 while allowing Varnish caching?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: AFAIK Magento's Varnish VCL caches in the *presence* of cookies. Your problematic point is probably *setting* them on every request, which results in sending negative caching headers and hitting [this code](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/PageCache/etc/varnish4.vcl#L184). Since you consume the cookies in Javascript, why not simply emit things directly into HTML/Javascript code, by your module.

Comment: Hello Danila, thank you for this feedback. I use this approach because I couldn't find any other way to format and return javascript code from Observers. For example, I detect "add to cart" events (event checkout_cart_add_product_complete). During such an action I retrieve all the information related to the product clicked in my Observer and add this data to the registry. Then, on a "controller_action_postdispatch" type event I read this registry and create my cookie which will be processed later on the front side. Do you know another way to proceed? Thank you